# How to get N2 by using maximum power?

Tags: power, resistors, transformer

Im finding N2 in this transformer but there’s no given Vs. The question asks if N1 = 280 turns, what is the value of N2 so that the 16 ohm resistor absorbs maximum power?

What I did for now is to refer the 16 ohm resistor to the primary to get the N2 variable but I don’t know how to connect it with the maximum power.

$$Z’_l = (\frac{N_1}{N_2})^2 16$$

$$Z’_l = (\frac{280}{N_2})^2 16$$
$$Z’_l = (\frac{78,400}{N_2}) 16$$

$$Z’_l = (\frac{1,254,400}{N_2})$$

This is what I did so far.

[image]

Comment: Consider the transfomer and 16 ohm resistor as a load impedance. Try to figure out when maximum power transfer will happen, from a voltage source Vs with a known source resistor (75 ohm).

Comment: You appear to have just completely dropped the unit of Ω from your calculations. Don't do that! Units are important.